# Symfony/Silex populate form with data from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, silex

I'm new to silex. Learning forms. I want to populate a form with data from database. I have this entity class

```
namespace NS\Entity\Admin;

    class Page
    {

    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $keywords;
    protected $description;
    protected $content;

    public function getId()     
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    etc......
```

Then in my controller

```
$page = new Page();
$form = $app['form.factory']->create(new UserForm(), $page);
etc ........
```

When the form is rendered it's fields are empty (which is normal)

If I do

```
$paget->setTitle = 'Title';
```

before rendering the form then the field title in the form is populated with the word Title.

So my question is how to populate the form fields with data from database? 
I guess somehow the properties of Page class should be populated with the data from the database but have no idea how to do that.

Short example will be useful.

Comment: Are you using Symfony 2 or Silex?  Your title implies Symfony but your (non-working)  example is Silex.  With Symfony it's easy using Doctrine ORM.  Silex does not come with a service for the Doctrine ORM.  You either need to add such a service or query your database using the dbal service then transfer the data to your $page object.

Comment: I mean silex in my example

Comment: The documentation is typically a good place to start: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html

Comment: You mean `$paget->setTitle('Title');` instead of `$paget->setTitle = 'Title';` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register the Entity Manager as a service:

```
$app['em'] = $app->share(function (Application $app) {
    $connection    = [
        'user'     => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => '3306',
        'dbname'   => 'database',
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    ];

    // If using annotations... e.g. /../Entity/Page.php
//    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
//        [__DIR__.'/../Entity'],
//        $app['debug'],
//        null,
//        null,
//        false // Use Simple Annotations
//    );

    // If using Yaml... e.g. /../config/orm/Page.orm.yml
    $config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__.'/../config/orm'], $app['debug']);

    $em = EntityManager::create($connection, $config);

    return $em;
});
```

Then in your controller you can use the Entity Manger's find method to load an entity. In this example I will load an id field from the $_GET parameters.

```
$app->get('/example', function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    $page = $app['em']->find('Page', $request->query->getInt('id'));

    if (!$page) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");
    }

    // ... pass page to form builder

    $form = $app['form.factory']->create(new UserForm(), $page);
});
```

Doctrine Entity Manager reference: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map